# Cell References in Cube Formula - Excel PowerPivot

Tags: cube, powerpivot

I'm looking to run a `CUBEVALUE` formula with member expressions based on the contents of multiple different cells. For this example i have 2 cells with a value for REGION in:

```
I15: Border
I16: Midlands
```

I can reference one cell successfully using a cube value formula:

```
=CUBEVALUE("PowerPivot Data","[Measures].[Sum of WEIGHTED_IMPRESSIONS]","[pvtBASE].[REGION].&["&I$15&"]")
```

Couldn't find a way within `CUBEVALUE` alone to replicate this result to reference both `I15` and `I16` so tried with a `CUBESET` then referencing the `CUBESET` in a later `CUBEVALUE` formula:

For the `CUBESET`, this formula works:

```
=CUBESET("PowerPivot Data",{"[pvtBASE].[REGION].&[Midlands]","[pvtBASE].[REGION].&[Border]"})
```

This formula works:

```
=CUBESET("PowerPivot Data","[pvtBASE].[REGION].&["&I15&"]")
```

But for some reason this doesn't:

```
=CUBESET("PowerPivot Data",{"[pvtBASE].[REGION].&["&I15&"]","[pvtBASE].[REGION].&["&I16&"]"})
```

Does anyone know how to fix the final `CUBESET` formula or if perhaps there is another way of fitting multiple members and cell references into a `CUBEVALUE` formula.

Feels like i'm close but then again I might not be!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Quotation marks go on the outside of the brackets rather than around each member. This works with AdventureWorks tabular model:

```
=CUBESET("AWCube","{[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].["& G17 & "],
[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].[" & G18 &"]}","TEST")
```

So your formula would be:

```
=CUBESET("PowerPivot Data","{[pvtBASE].[REGION].&["& I15 &"],
[pvtBASE].[REGION].&["& I16  &"]}")
```

The last argument in my cubeset formula is a name, which is optional. I give the cubeset a name so I can see it. Otherwise, the name comes back as blank and I forget that it is in that cell.